How to securely manage the password provided by the client to configure the database connection in Laravel?
I am a beginner in Laravel development, and I am building an API where each client will use their own instance and must configure their database connection during an initial setup process. The requirement is that each client provides their database credentials through a configuration endpoint.
Since the API won’t have a database until it’s configured, I need the client to first provide an initial password to access this endpoint. My main concern is how to securely handle this initial password during the setup process.
Would it be secure to store this password in the .env file or another configuration file? Or is there a better approach to managing this password while ensuring it is not exposed or compromised?
What are the best practices for securely handling this initial password, and how can I implement them in Laravel?

What is your actual concern? What is the problem with .env file? When you know the password already, would you store it in the .env file? If so - what is the difference then?

also, why only password? What about host, username and database name?

The DB engine should have securely stored the password and username in its configuration files after setup if it is up to date.
If u want to re check it without using the dB connection itself a more secure practice compared to store it in a plaintext file, would be to hash the password with a secure password hashing function provided by a trusted 3rd party library that is available through PHP.
It should be compared to the the user input and if the two match you can tell it is the same password. This is a deeper topic in itself.
Then also have a mechanism to update the library, the function and password in case of problems.

Are you sure this password must be hashed?

Yes, storing passwords in plaintext is a bad practice they can be stolen and refused maliciously. Instead of only  securing the environnement, consider that a compromision will happend anyway.

Do you understand that a hashed password cannot be used?

It should be compared to the hash of the user input and if the two match you can tell it is the same. but I didn't explain it in detail my OP.

Do you understand this is a database password?

Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

No, it is a password stored in a file.

You may want to re-read the question you are trying to answer, in order for fully comprehend it. In case you cannot understand what is asked here, I would suggest to delete your answer.
